# Resources for learning about Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I've spent the last year learning and using Java in university but we didn't do much (read: anything) in terms of Threading.

We do some next year but I'm hopeful I'll be able to get a head start over the summer.

What are the best resources for learning about and getting to grips with Threading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this program: http://javaconcurrenta.sourceforge.net/

with this program you learn visually java threads.